# Get last item of nested object

Tags: javascript

I'm working with real nested objects, sometimes 10 levels deep, and the last item is always a property with a number, example:

```
let myObject = {

  levelOne: {
    levelTwo: {
      levelThree: 1
    }
  }
};
```

I would like to know if is possible, without knowing the exactly name of the properties, get the last item and increase the number by 1.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes its possible, with for,in and recursion

Comment: Have you tried recursion?

Comment: I guess you mean "innermost", not "last" - object properties are not ordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind this could be optimized and a use of hasOwnProperty should probably be used.

You could also switch the recursion to a while.

This is not the best solution just an example.

Here you go:

```
let myObject = {
  levelOne: {
    levelTwo: {
      levelThree: 1
    }
  }
};

function getLast(object){
  if (typeof object !== 'object'){
    return object;
  }
  for ( prop in object){
    return getLast(object[prop])
  }
}

console.log(getLast(myObject));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o18hde10/1/

Comment: This will just return the first non object value.

Answer (score 1):

Here is function get inner object:

```
function innerObject(o) { 
  return Object.keys(o).reduce(function (r, k) { 
    return typeof o[k] === 'object' ? innerObject(o[k]) : (r[k] = o[k], r) 
  }, {}) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive function to get the last key and return its value using ++.

```
let myObject = {

    levelOne: {
        levelTwo: {
            levelThree: 1
        }
    }
};

function getLastKey(object) {
    for (const key in object) {
        if (typeof object[key] === 'object') {
            getLastKey(object[key]);
        } else {
            return object[key]++;
        }
    }
}

getLastKey(myObject)
console.log(myObject)
```

If you have any questions make sure to ask them!

Answer (score -1):

Below is some pseudocode using underscore to loop through your keys.  You will need to modify it depending on your input data.

```
function findObject(){
    _.some(myobject, function(val){
        if(_.isObject(val)){
            findObject(val);
        }
        if(_.isNumber(val)){
            return val;
        }
    });
}
```